# Scraping Site Data with out Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

Currently I am trying to pull CMS historical data from there site. I have got some working code to pull the download links from the page. My problem is that the links are divided into pages. I need to iterate through all the available pages and extract the download links. The obvious choice here is to use Selenium to click next pages and get data. Due to company policy i can not run selenium in the environment. Is there a way I can got through the pages and extract link. The website does not show the post link once you try to go to next page. I am out of ideas to try and get to next page without post link or not using selenium.

Current working code to pull links from first page

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
#from selenium import webdriver
from lxml import html
import requests



def http_request_get(url, session=None, payload=None, parse=True):
""" Sends a GET HTTP request to a website and returns its HTML content and full url address. """

if payload is None:
    payload = {}

if session:
    content = session.get(url, params=payload, verify=False, headers={"content-type":"text"})
else:
    content = requests.get(url, params=payload, verify=False, headers={"content-type":"text"})

content.raise_for_status()  # Raise HTTPError for bad requests (4xx or 5xx)

if parse:
    return html.fromstring(content.text), content.url
else:
    return content.text, content.url

def get_html(link):
"""
Returns a html.
"""
page_parsed, _ = http_request_get(url=link, payload={'t': ''}, parse=True)
return page_parsed


cmslink = "https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and- 
Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Monthly-Contract-and-Enrollment-Summary-Report"
content, _ = http_request_get(url=cmslink,payload={'t':''},parse=True)
linkTable = content.cssselect('td[headers="view-dlf-1-title-table-column"]')[0]
headers = linkTable[0].xpath('//a/@href')
df1     =  pd.DataFrame(headers,columns= ['links'])
df1SubSet = df1[df1['links'].str.contains('contract-summary', case=False)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the two urls that will give you the total 166 entries. I have also changed the condition for capturing `hrefs`. Give this a try.

```
cmslinks=[
'https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Monthly-Contract-and-Enrollment-Summary-Report?items_per_page=100&items_per_page_options%5B5%5D=5%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B10%5D=10%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B25%5D=25%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B50%5D=50%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B100%5D=100%20per%20page&combine=&page=0',
'https://www.cms.gov/Research-Statistics-Data-and-Systems/Statistics-Trends-and-Reports/MCRAdvPartDEnrolData/Monthly-Contract-and-Enrollment-Summary-Report?items_per_page=100&items_per_page_options%5B5%5D=5%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B10%5D=10%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B25%5D=25%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B50%5D=50%20per%20page&items_per_page_options%5B100%5D=100%20per%20page&combine=&page=1']

df=pd.DataFrame()
for cmslink in cmslinks:
    print(cmslink)
    content, _ = http_request_get(url=cmslink,payload={'t':''},parse=True)
    linkTable = content.cssselect('td[headers="view-dlf-1-title-table-column"]')[0]
    headers = linkTable[0].xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Contract Summary') or contains(text(),'Monthly Enrollment by CPSC')]/@href")
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(headers,columns= ['links'])
    df=df.append(df1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The looping of these links just duplicated on first page links on first page.

Comment: Just to make sure...could you please please post your full loop in an update of the question, as I don't get the issue at my end.

Comment: df=pd.DataFrame() 
for csmlink in cmslinks:
    content, _ = http_request_get(url=cmslink,payload={'t':''},parse=True)
    linkTable = content.cssselect('td[headers="view-dlf-1-title-table-column"]')[0]
    headers = linkTable[0].xpath('//a/@href')
    df1     =  pd.DataFrame(headers,columns= ['links'])
    df1SubSet = df1[df1['links'].str.contains('contract-summary', case=False)]
    df=df.append(df1SubSet)

Comment: See updated answer. Changed the way you build "headers".

Comment: Yes that worked sorry my internet was down just saw your port. It works thank you!